# how to convert number to bar code using cloudfunction and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsbarcode

how to implement this jsbarcode npm on convert phone or mobile number  to bar code using cloud function and nodejs

```
var jsbarcode = require("jsbarcode")
<img id="barcode"/>
$("#barcode").JsBarcode("Hi!");
JsBarcode("#barcode", "1234", {
  format: "pharmacode",
  lineColor: "#0aa",
  width:4,
  height:40,
  displayValue: false
});
```

Comment: What the function of `<img id="barcode"/>` and `$("#barcode").JsBarcode("Hi!");` why is it there?

Comment: This is jsbarcode npm example code, then how to convert cloud function code

Comment: Answered your question

Comment: one doubt how to pass the number on barcode and how to store the jsbarcode on database

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it answers your question

Answer (score 3):

For using JsBarcode in NodeJS, you need **canvas** ([node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)), not HTML image tag.

Install canvas

```sh
npm install canvas
```

Then use it with `jsbarcode`

```js
const JsBarcode = require('jsbarcode');
const { Canvas } = require("canvas");

const number = getNumberFromWherever()

// Create a new canvas
const canvas = new Canvas();
JsBarcode(canvas, number, {
  format: "pharmacode",
  lineColor: "#0aa",
  width:4,
  height:40,
  displayValue: false
});

// Get Data URL and save it to the DB

canvas.toDataURL('image/png', (err, png) => {
  // Do whatever you want to do
  // for storing in the DB
})
```

Please refer node-canvas GitHub page for more details.